# How can I get the list of app pool using appcmd.exe

Tags: iis, windows-command-prompt, application-pools, appcmd

we using the below command to get the list of the site added in is:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe list sites
```

but the above command can not take a list of app pools related to the site.

I want a list of app pools. if a single command to viewing list of site and related app pool, really good.

Comment: Do you get any error running the command? E.g. something about _insufficient permissions_? Please [edit] the question and share full traceback (sanitized if necessary).

Comment: If you study some basic IIS concepts, then you can answer your own questions. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis Since application pools are associated with only applications, it is impossible to achieve what you wanted when querying sites. Similarly, physical paths are associated only with virtual directories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

below command, get the list of the application pools:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe list apppool
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do in powershell via [**`Get-IISAppPool`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iisapppool?view=windowsserver2022-ps) in the [**`IISAdministration`** Module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/?view=windowsserver2022-ps) like this:

```
Import-Module IISAdministration

Get-IISAppPool
```